# Silex PHP - How to populate $app with dynamic keys from custom service provider after register()

Tags: php, silex, service-provider

I'm the developer for [m1/vars](http://github.com/m1/vars), which is a config loader service provider for Silex, what I want to know to make my library more useful is how to go about dynamically loading keys into `$app` after registering the service and dealing with the secondary parameters of `$app->register()`.

For example this is how it currently works:

app.php:

```
$app->register(new M1\Vars\Provider\Silex\VarsServiceProvider('example.yml'), [
    'vars.path' => __DIR__,
    'vars.options' => [
        // options here
    ]
]);

$app['vars.merge']();
```

VarsServiceProvider.php:

```
$app['vars'] = function ($app) {
    return new Vars($this->entity, $this->createOptions($app));
};

$app['vars.merge'] = $app->protect(function() use ($app) {
    static $initialized = false;
    if ($initialized) {
        return;
    }
    $initialized = true;

    foreach ($app['vars']->toDots(false) as $key => $value) {
        $app[$key] = $value;
    }
});
```

What this basically does is it loads the stuff from the config file (`example.yml`) lazily -- so when accessing `$app['vars']` it loads -- so the `$app['vars.options']` will be available as it has already been defined in the second parameter of `register()`. `$app['vars.merge']` loads the data from `$app['vars']` into `$app`, for example if you defined:

example.yml

```
monolog.logfile: %dir%/../../app/logs/app/dev.log
```

After `$app['vars.merge']()` you could then load the above from `$app['monolog.logfile']` instead of `$app['vars']['monolog.logfile']`

What I'm aiming for is getting rid of `$app['vars.merge']` as it doesn't seem right to me and seems a bit hacky but the problem is the `$app['vars.options']` and `$app['vars.path']` have to be available for `$app['vars']` and I don't want to have to call `$app['vars']` before I can call `$app['vars.monolog.logfile']`.

Any ideas, if it doesn't make sense I'll try and explain a bit more?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, why don't you just call `app['vars.merge']` directly from your provider? In fact, you could avoid the `vars.merge` function and just call the for each inside the register function.

In order to make your provider more Silex friendly I would probably implement the foreach inside the [boot method](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/ServiceProviderInterface.php#L36) of your provider.

The signature from this method is simple: `public function boot(Application $app);` and the docs may me think that this is what you probably want:

> Bootstraps the application.
>
> This method is called after all services are registered
>   and should be used for "dynamic" configuration (whenever
>   a service must be requested).

So your boot method should look like:

```
<?php
// ...
class VarsServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    // ...
    public function boot(Application $app)
    {
        foreach ($app['vars']->toDots(false) as $key => $value) {
            $app[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

My main concern with the boot method is that the parameters will be loaded once the application is booted which may be a little too late in some circumstances, you should do some research about that (it that's the case then just put the foreach inside the `register` method).

### Second attempt

Seeing that none of this options are valid for your use case, what about defining your service like so?

```
<?php
// Service Provider
$app['vars'] = function ($app) {
    $instance = new Vars($this->entity, $this->createOptions($app));

    foreach ($instance->toDots(false) as $key => $value) {
        $app[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $instance;
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your reply. I actually tried your method of doing the foreach in register but this made it run before vars.options was available. As for moving the logic to boot; this is too late due to the data that vars sets has to be available for other service providers when registering.

Comment: @MilesCroxford, how about now? Does this new approach suit your needs?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is due to you have to call `$app['vars']` so it runs through that anonymous function so therefore `$app` only gets populated with stuff in my original example like `$app['monolog.logfile']` when you call `$app['vars']` instead of what I hope to achieve which is that `$app` automatically gets populated when registering. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean to get the 'vars.options' array into the ```$app``` instance? If that's the case it should be doable in the register method. If you mean to import more options it would be tricky...

Comment: No, i mean to get the data fetched from vars to be imported globally into `$app`, but the `vars` instance relies on `$app['vars.options']` so therefore you have to wait till you call `$app['vars']` until the instance is made, then from which you can import the data fetched from `$app['vars']` globally into `$app` -- my problem is I don't want to have to call `$app['vars']` in say for example `app.php`, I just want to be able to call the data fetched from `$app['vars']` straight from `$app`

Comment: Well, for your explanation, you can easily extrapolate that you can't do what you want. If your intend is to have all vars into ```$app``` then you definetely need a ```vars``` instance therefore you must call ```$app['vars']``` otherwise your vars won't get resolved so they can't be imported into the ```$app```